# Grep not honoring --exclude-dir

Tags: linux, grep

I'm having trouble searching in `/var` due to a hang at `/var/run`. I tried to [exclude `/var/run`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692318/608639), but its not producing expected results:

```
$ sudo grep -IR --exclude-dir="/var/run" '45.78.157.165' /var | egrep -v '(audit|access)'
/var/log/secure:Jun 21 14:08:34 cryptopp sshd[19729]: error: Received disconnect from 199.91.135.157: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: 45.78.157.165 [preauth]
/var/log/secure-20160626:Jun 21 14:08:34 cryptopp sshd[19729]: error: Received disconnect from 199.91.135.157: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: 45.78.157.165 [preauth]
/var/log/secure-20160626:Jun 21 14:08:34 cryptopp sshd[19729]: error: Received disconnect from 199.91.135.157: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: 45.78.157.165 [preauth]
grep: /var/run/saslauthd/mux: No such device or address
grep: /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such device or address
grep: /var/run/rpcbind.sock: No such device or address
grep: /var/run/udev/control: No such device or address
```

I've tried both `-exclude-dir=/var/run` and `-exclude-dir="/var/run"`. Both produce the same results.

Why is my grep failing?

How do I exclude `/var/run` from a recursive grep?

---

CentOS 7.2, with Grep:

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it's probably because you're explicitly asking `grep` to search recursively from `/var`, and `/var/run` does not match a SUBDIRECTORY under `/var`.

See grep man page, which states:

```
--exclude-dir=glob
    [..] skip any subdirectory whose base name matches glob.  [..]
```

### FIX

Therefore, to fix your command, change the exclude pattern, i.e.:

```
sudo grep -IR --exclude-dir="run" '45.78.157.165' /var | egrep -v '(audit|access)'
```

Comment: I have a similar question to this.  How would you change `grep -r --exclude-dir=./root/js sometext .` to exclude a subfolder from current location?

Comment: Not sure the `/`s do anything.  grep goes into each folder and begins the search at that point.  It is effectively always searching the current folder.  If you want to exclude a sub-folder (e.g. `/home/me/dev/project1/js`) and you're searching from many folders up (e.g. starting at `/home/me`), then you need to specify the one base folder name you want to exclude (e.g. `--exclude-dir=js`).  Unfortunately, this will also exclude ANY sub-folder of the same name, elsewhere in the hierarchy.  If you want something with more control, you can try to look at using `find` with `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit in other words shorter, because it needs a sub-directory, which is in not an absolute path in overwhelming majority of cases (=excluding searching from the root itself, where it thus might work)